# How to display tabular data as column instead of individual rows

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I created a table in SSRS which shows the following:

[image]

Is there any way to have the `Date Of Last Credentialing` and `Credentialing Expiration` to appear as column group rather than individual row?

Something like this:

```
Date Of Last Credentialing     Credentialing Expiration     Date Of Last Credentialing     Credentialing Expiration     Date Of Last Credentialing     Credentialing Expiration
2007-12-24                     2010-12-23                   2012-04-25                          2014-04-24              2013-10-14                     2016-10-13
```

[image]

Comment: Pivoting might be an answer http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/11g/pivot-and-unpivot-operators-11gr1.php  You could also do this programatically after the records are returned with some simple code logic

Comment: In SSRS or in SQL itself? Also each individual will have different number of those entries.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add row groups to the level that you need on a row by row basis. Then add two column groups based on, it looks like date then scheduling type, from your example.

If your query returns fields for date and type within whatever row groups then add a column group based on the date field and a child group based on the type. This will push your columns out as desired.

[image]

Comment: Should I do this in a TABLE or MATRIX?

Comment: Hi, I would go with a matrix.

Comment: I updated my question with all my fields and please let me know which is going where...

Comment: I have the Matrix working, except if the entity appears more than one, the date is shown for only one. If you can please help me figure that out.

Comment: I bet the DateOfLast field is not being truncated. You would get two entries for one day if your date is returning multiple times of the day.

Comment: What do you suggest I do? How do I ensure it is being truncated?

Comment: If the date is day based I would truncate it in the database. If you have to do it in the report then you can right click the column group then select group properties and set the Group Expression =SomeFunctionToTruncateDate(Fields!DateValue.Value)

Comment: The date is already being truncated... in my query. Here it is: `CAST(RTRIM(ww.attr1836) AS Date) 'DateOfLastCredentialing',
CAST(RTRIM(ww.attr1837) AS Date) 'CredentialingExpiration',`

Comment: Where would you put each fields based on what I provided? I can test it out if you show me :)

Comment: I'll ad one more comment. If you place a row header in the matrix outside of all row groups then you can merge the column cells on that row and make it a nice header for the whole width of the column group

Comment: I am new to this Matrix so I am just having a hard time implementing of what is being said.